# Compare column of datatable with manipulated value

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a Data table say like having columns

ID  CHKdigit

1   dav454

2   sv456

3   yt89889

I have to check for chkdigit that is it correct with an algorithm

say i have a function for algorith

```
function string algocheck(string strchk)
{
// rules of algos

retun str;
}
```

so basicaly i will pass each row chkdigit of datatable to check its up to algo or not

like in sql we write query

```
select columnname from table where column = algocheck(columnname)
```

how to get similar concept with data table without running loop

I am stuck on runnig loop but i want to avoid that thing

Thanks

Comment: If your algo is simple enough to be described for `DataTable.Select()` function, you might try it. Like `DataRow[] CheckResults = MyDataTable.Select("SomeField > 1 AND AnotherField IN (1, 2, 3)");`

Comment: What is the problem with a loop? Any query based on in memory datatable would required direct or indirect loop anyway

Comment: Yeah. Even if you describe the query with Linq, the compiler will run a loop anyways.

Comment: @Taosique i have to compare for same fields, and i dont want to run loop because of code lengthiness